# Get polar opposite for every word in google cloud nlp api

Tags: python, nlp, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-nl, google-natural-language

I'm working with Google Cloud NLP Api with Python(3.6), my client asked to get **polar-opposite/replaced-word-for-opposite-word** for every word of provided text file.

Here's what I have tried:

From views.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form
    obj.textFile = form.cleaned_data['textFile']
    obj.save()
    text_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'texts/', obj.textFile.name)
    txt = Path(text_path).read_text(encoding='cp1252')
    service = discovery.build('language', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials)
    service_request = service.documents().analyzeSentiment(
        body={
            'document': {
                'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
                'content': txt
            }
        }
    )
    response = service_request.execute()
    print(response)
```

Here's the response:

```
{'documentSentiment': {'polarity': 0.3, 'magnitude': 0.1, 'score': 0}, 'language': 'en', 'sentences': [{'text': {'content': 'hello!', 'beginOffset': -1}, 'sentiment': {'polarity': 1, 'magnitude': 0, 'score': 0}}, {'text': {'content': 'This is Abdul.', 'beginOffset': -1}, 'sentiment': {'polarity': -1, 'magnitude': 0, 'score': 0}}]}
```

I have explored the documentation of Google's NLP API, but couldn't find any option to get polar opposite for every word.

Is there any possible option to achieve this?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post examples of input and output that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The analyzeSentiment method of NLP API, returns:

- The overall sentiment of the input document.
- The language of the text.
- A list of sentences, which contains the sentiment of each sentence.

It is probably easier to see those parameters in the [REST API reference](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/documents/analyzeSentiment#response-body).

If the information you are looking for is not there, it probably means the feature you want is not supported yet.

You can open a feature request describing your requirements and providing some examples of what you want to accomplish, by filling this [form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187079&template=1161362). This doesn’t guarantee the feature would be included, but this is a good way to bring your requirement to Google engineers attention. Opening a feature request also allows other users to upvote the request if it is relevant for them.